# How do you upload a video to a node js server in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3, nativescript

In my nativescript app, I'm able to record a video, but I want to upload it to an S3 bucket for later streaming. I'm running a node js server that handles the api for my app.

I'm trying to use the 'nativescript-background-http' library, but it always breaks when I try to run the `uploadFile` function.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var uploadVideo = function (filepath) {
    console.log("Attempting to upload video...");
    var session = bghttp.session("video-upload");
    var filename = filepath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    var request = {
        url: config.apiUrl + 'upload',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "File-Name": filename
        },
        description: "{ 'uploading': filename }"
    };
    try {
        var task = session.uploadFile(filepath, request);

        task.on("progress", logEvent);
        task.on("error", logEvent);
        task.on("complete", logEvent);

        function logEvent(e) {
            console.log("Logging event.");
            console.dir(e);
            console.log(e.eventName);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.dir(error);
        console.log("An error occurred uploading the file. Removing video from filesystem...");

        var documents = fs.knownFolders.documents();
        var file = documents.getFile(filename);
        file.remove()
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log("The video has been removed successfully.");
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("The video could not be removed from the file system.");
                console.dir(error);
            });
    }
};
```

This is the output I end up with:

```
JS: Video located at /data/user/0/org.nativescript.Lifey/files/videoCapture_1486072596043.mp4
JS: Attempting to upload video...
JS: === dump(): dumping members ===
JS: {
JS:     "nativeException": {
JS:         "constructor": "constructor()function () { [native code] }"
JS:     }
JS: }
JS: === dump(): dumping function and properties names ===
JS: === dump(): finished ===
JS: An error occurred uploading the file. Removing video from filesystem...
JS: The video has been removed successfully.
```

Any idea what's going on? Does 'nativescript-background-http' library even support video uploads (I've only seen image upload examples on their github)? Is there some alternative that I could use if I can't use that library?

Comment: Can you try uploading an image to see if that works? I'd also try sending the request to http://requestb.in and see if the HTTP request is being constructed the way you want.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to upload an image instead to a private requestb.in, and it worked great. I tried doing it to my server as well. It didn't go through to my server just right, but it at least initiated the upload before returning an error. It logged a message in the server console to indicate that it went to the right route.

Comment: What about sending a video to requestbin?

Comment: Nothing comes through for the video. Even requestb.in doesn't get the request or do anything about it when I refresh to see updates.

Comment: Safe to say then the problem is definitely the lib. Might be a buffering problem? Does it support any `pipe()`ing?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I haven't seen any examples for other data types in their documentation which makes me wonder if it supports anything other than images. I haven't picked up on angular 2, so I don't know if it supports `pipe()`ing. Their github, api reference, and website are all listed on their npm package page though if you would know more about that: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http).